# How can I reduce extract features from a set of Matrices and vectors to be used in Machine Learning in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, feature-extraction, dimensionality-reduction

I have a task where I need to train a machine learning model to predict a set of outputs from multiple inputs. My inputs are 1000 iterations of a set of 3x 1 vectors, a set of 3x3 covariance matrices and a set of scalars, while my output is just a set of scalars. I cannot use regression learner app because these inputs need to have the same dimensions, any idea on how to unify them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to solve this is to flatten the covariance matrix into a vector. Once you did that, you can construct a 1000xN matrix where 1000 refers to the number of samples in your dataset and N is the number of features. For example if your features consist of a 3x1 vector, a 3x3 covariance matrix and lets say 5 other scalars, N could be 3+3*3+5=17. You then use this matrix to train an arbitrary model such as a linear regressor or more advanced models like a tree or the like.

When training machine learning models it is important to understand your data and exploit its structure to help the learning algorithms. For example we could use the fact that a covariance matrix is symmetric and positive semi-definite and thus lives in a [closed convex cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153530/set-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-is-a-full-dimensional-convex-con). Symmetry of the matrix implies that it lives in a subspace of the set of all 3x3 matrices. In fact the dimension of the space of 3x3 symmetric matrices [is only 6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185802/dimensions-of-symmetric-and-skew-symmetric-matrices). You can use that knowledge to reduce redundancy in your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am kind of new to MATLAB, so i dont really know how to implement this.

Comment: What kind of machine learning model do you have in mind? A more accurate answer to your question would require us to know that.

Comment: I am trying to apply SVM regression